# Setting up SQL queries with multiple parameters

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to set up a SQL query with multiple parameters that are being pulled from the URL. So far I can only get it to work with the there is only one item in the URL.

My default query to pull in all the content

```
$sql = "SELECT "; 
$sql .= "* ";
$sql .= "FROM ";
$sql .= "cms_site_content ";
$sql .= "WHERE ";
$sql .= "1";
```

I then check if anything was passed through the URL and retrieve it.

```
if (isset($_GET["d"])) {
$d=$_GET["d"];
```

Inside the if statement, I break the values passed as "d" into separate items

```
$newD = explode(',',$d);
$countD = count($newD);


foreach($newD as $discipline) {

if ($countD == 1) {
            $sql .= " AND";
    $sql .= " discipline='".$discipline."'";
}
```

My problem is getting the SQL to work if there is more than one discipline value. It should read something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM cms_site_content WHERE 1 AND discipline="value"
```

however if there's more than one discipline value, it should read:

```
SELECT * FROM cms_site_content WHERE 1 AND discipline="value OR discipline="value2" OR discipline="value3"
```

Is there a more efficient way to write this? I can't figure out how to insert the OR into the foreach statement.

Comment: There are great libraries and frameworks out there that does all this for you including the security, why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: You should read how to use PDO with MySQL : http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: You can use round braces to make 'blocks' of checks (`SELECT * FROM cms_site_content WHERE 1 AND (discipline = "value" OR discipline = "value2")`). I suggest removing the `1 AND` block to make it easier for yourself, or even use a framework/library that does the job for you.

Comment: Can you recommend any simple libraries to look into? I just started learning PHP and I'm not sure where to begin

Comment: Using a library for something like this is an overkill in my opinion. At the end of the day, SQL queries are simply strings. All you need is a bit of code to generate the string containing multiple conditions i.e. `discipline = 'option1' OR  discipline = 'option2' OR discipline = 'option3'`, etc. see answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save all discipline values in an array;

```
$discipline_arr = array();
foreach($newD as $discipline) {

    $discipline_arr[] = $discipline; 
    // by the way, don't forget to escape for sql injection 
    // mysql_escape_string is the depracated one, u can use that if u have no 
    // other choice 
    
            
}
```

Then in your sql, add them as discipline in ('value1','value2', 'etc ...') condition (that is for strings, for numeric types it would be like discipline in (1,2,3,4, etc)

```
$sql = " SELECT * FROM cms_site_content WHERE 1 " . 
    (empty($discipline_arr) ? "" : "and 
         discipline in ('". implode("','" , $discipline_arr). "') ") ;
```

Link to escaping
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php

Comment: +1, Good job, I like your response better. Didn't know you can use `in()` like that.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, I saw this on your profile "10 kinds of people in the world, those who understand binary and those who don't." very clever

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the rest of your query is in tact. Simply store all of your discipline values in an array as follows, then feed the `$discipline_string` to your `$sql` query:

```
$discipline_ary = array('option1', 'option2', 'option3');
$discipline_string = "";

for($i=0; $i < count($discipline_ary); $i++){
    $discipline_string .= " discipline = '" . $discipline[$i] . "' ";

    if($i+1 == count($discipline_ary)){
       break;
    }else{
       $discipline_string .= " OR "
    }
}
```